# how to get flags based on app code and year

Tags: mysql, sql

below is the given table in DB

| ID | org_id | app_code | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 205 | EBB | 2016 |
| 2 | 205 | EBB | 2016 |
| 3 | 205 | LF | 2017 |
| 4 | 205 | LF | 2017 |
| 5 | 205 | LF | 2018 |
| 6 | 205 | LF | 2018 |
| 7 | 205 | LF | 2019 |
| 8 | 205 | LF | 2019 |
| 9 | 205 | EBB | 2020 |
| 10 | 205 | EBB | 2020 |
| 11 | 205 | LF | 2020 |
| 12 | 205 | LF | 2020 |
| 13 | 205 | EBB | 2021 |
| 14 | 205 | EBB | 2021 |
| 15 | 205 | LF | 2021 |
| 16 | 205 | LF | 2021 |
| 17 | 205 | LF | 2022 |
| 18 | 205 | LF | 2022 |
| 19 | 205 | EBB | 2022 |
| 20 | 205 | EBB | 2022 |

expected output is

| ID | org_id | app_code | year | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 205 | EBB | 2016 | 2 |
| 2 | 205 | EBB | 2016 | 2 |
| 3 | 205 | LF | 2017 | 1 |
| 4 | 205 | LF | 2017 | 1 |
| 5 | 205 | LF | 2018 | 1 |
| 6 | 205 | LF | 2018 | 1 |
| 7 | 205 | LF | 2019 | 1 |
| 8 | 205 | LF | 2019 | 1 |
| 9 | 205 | EBB | 2020 | 3 |
| 10 | 205 | EBB | 2020 | 3 |
| 11 | 205 | LF | 2020 | 3 |
| 12 | 205 | LF | 2020 | 3 |
| 13 | 205 | EBB | 2021 | 3 |
| 14 | 205 | EBB | 2021 | 3 |
| 15 | 205 | LF | 2021 | 3 |
| 16 | 205 | LF | 2021 | 3 |
| 17 | 205 | LF | 2022 | 3 |
| 18 | 205 | LF | 2022 | 3 |
| 19 | 205 | EBB | 2022 | 3 |
| 20 | 205 | EBB | 2022 | 3 |

if ALL the app code for a particular year is LF then 1

if ALL the app code for a particular year is EBB the 2

if the app code for a particular year having both LF and EBB the 3.

need help in SQL

Comment: And what did you try? Share some code that didn't work for you and explain where you are stuck. SO is not code writing service.

Comment: It seems that a simple case condition will help ? Have you tried something ? Which dbms are you really using ?

Comment: Please tag only a single rdbms

Comment: Simple CASE expression should be enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also, MySQL <> SQL-server. Select one, whichever you are using.

Comment: i have used case, not except .. but could get results .. Please help

Comment: i need in MYSQL  @Aarlaneth

Comment: Read through documentation provided in comment by @PawełDyl, try again and then share what you tried (code that you tried running but didn't work) inside your question.

Comment: What is **precise** version of your MySQL server?

Comment: Thank you .. i have so many org_id  is not same like the above input  . example : some org_id in 2016 will have both LF and EBB  , some org_id in 2017 will have only EBB as app code  @Aarlaneth

Comment: ALL the app_codes have to be the same for a year for 1 or 2 to apply , A row by row case statement does not suffice I have edited the question to stress ALL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To calculate flags for each year and org_id separately you can use following query:

```
SELECT *,
MAX(CASE WHEN app_code='EBB' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY org_id, year) +
MAX(CASE WHEN app_code='LF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY org_id, year) Flag
FROM T
```

If version < 8.0 you can use more complex query:

```
SELECT T.*, F.Flag
FROM T
JOIN (
  SELECT org_id, year, CASE WHEN IsEBB=1 AND IsLF=1 THEN 3 WHEN IsEBB=1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END Flag
    FROM (
      SELECT org_id, year, MAX(CASE app_code WHEN 'EBB' then 1 END) IsEBB, MAX(CASE app_code WHEN 'LF' then 1 END) IsLF
      FROM T
    GROUP BY org_id, year
  ) Group1
) F ON T.org_id=F.org_id AND T.year=F.year
```